# Python loops - turtle object

Tags: python

Guys I am learning how to code. And I am starting off with python turtle object. At this point of time working on learning loops.

### **This is what i have written so far:**

```
amy=turtle.Turtle()

amy.penup()
amy.back(100)
amy.pendown()

amy.width(10)
amy.speed(0)

for lovelycolor in ["blue","pink","red","orange","yellow","green"]:
    amy.color(lovelycolor)
    amy.forward(50)
    amy.left(60)

amy.penup()
amy.forward(50)
amy.left(60)
amy.forward(50)
amy.penup()
amy.forward(75)
amy.pendown() 


#here i need it to loop the hexagon 6 more times
```

This is working perfectly fine and creating a rainbow color hexagone. However I want this to loop and create similar hexagon 6 more times in a circle. Each hexagon should have the six colors i have mentioned in the code.

Can someone please guide me as my loops aren't working the way i mentioned above.

Comment: You should specify `import turtle` for your code to execute properly for testers

Comment: `create similar hexagon 6 more times in a circle` you mean all around the first hexagon sharing a common side ?

Comment: hi david, yes all around the first hexagon.

Comment: do you want to iterate the same hexagon 6 more time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add another loop around the first one (mind the indentation), and move and turn the turtle a bit in between the execution of the inner loop. 
Depending on how exactly you want your circle of circles to look you may have to experiment a bit with the forward movement and turning in the outer loop. Something like this:

```
for _ in range(6):
    for lovelycolor in ["blue","pink","red","orange","yellow","green"]:
        amy.color(lovelycolor)
        amy.forward(50)
        amy.left(60)
    amy.forward(100)
    amy.right(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import turtle
amy=turtle.Turtle()

amy.penup()
amy.back(100)
amy.pendown()
amy.width(10)
amy.speed(0)
for i in range(6):
    for lovelycolor in ["blue","pink","red","orange","yellow","green"]:
        amy.color(lovelycolor)
        amy.forward(50)
        amy.left(60)
amy.penup()
amy.forward(50)
amy.left(60)
amy.forward(50)
amy.penup()
amy.forward(75)
amy.pendown()
```

Comment: Thank You Yashi! just that this is iterating the hexagon on the same spot. But it does help in understanding the concept

Answer (score 0):

Finally find a way to have different colors (quite dirty, as I found no doc on this on the Web)

```py
import turtle


def hexagon(t, i_color_list, sens=1):
    lovelycolors = ["blue", "pink", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green"]
    for i in range(6):
        t.color(lovelycolors[i_color_list[i]])
        print(i, lovelycolors[i_color_list[i]])
        t.forward(50)
        t.left(60*sens)


def choose_colors_order(premiere=2):
    p = premiere
    hexagon_colors = []
    for i in range(1, 6):
        l = list(range(6))
        #
        nb2 = (i+1) % 6
        nb3 = i
        l.remove(premiere)
        if nb2 in l:
            l.remove(nb2)
            nl = [premiere, nb2]
        else:
            nl = [premiere]
        l.remove(nb3)
        nl += l + [i]
        premiere = nl[-2]
        hexagon_colors += [nl]
    # last hexagon
    l = list(range(6))
    l.remove(premiere)
    l.remove(p)
    l.remove(0)
    nl = [premiere] + l + [p, 0]
    hexagon_colors += [nl]
    return hexagon_colors


amy = turtle.Turtle()
amy.pendown()
amy.width(10)
amy.speed(0)

hexagon(amy, range(6))
ordered_colors = choose_colors_order()
for i in range(6):
    amy.up()
    amy.forward(50)
    amy.right(60)
    amy.down()
    hexagon(amy, ordered_colors[i])
    amy.left(120)
    print(i, ordered_colors[i])

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]